# MVC Views can't reference assembilies

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

Is there a reason why i can't reference any assemblies from my master page or views?

So for example in my controler classes I can go MyRootnamespace.OtherAssembly.ClassName but when I do this in my view like:
    <% MyRootnamespace.OtherAssembly.ClassName %>

it says OtherAssembly does not belong to MyRootnamespace

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the line

```
<add namespace="MyApp.MyNamespace"/>
```

to the namespaces section of your web.config.

Comment: If you namespace is correct, It doesn't require recompile project or solution. Because IIS detect & restart application automatically when web.config file is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Before using new namespace in Asp.net Mvc page like master page, view page. Please add namespace(s) that you want to use to web.config file.

> ```
> <configuration>
>     <system.web>
>         <pages>
>             <namespaces>
>                 <add namespace="[Your Namespace]" />
>             </namespaces>
>         </pages>
>     </system.web>  
> </configuration>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably register the assembly as in a Webform, like on http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321749

```
<%@ Register Assembly= "MyRootnamespace.OtherAssembly" %>
```